# evaluating the limit $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \tan (2x + \pi/2)$.

Tags: limits

Find :

$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \tan (2x + \pi/2)$

By looking at the graph of the function :

$f$ goes to $-\infty$  if x approaches 0 from right

and $f$ goes to $+\infty$  if x approaches 0 from left

---

But I am interested in finding the limit algebraically, without using its graph

If we substitute $0$ in the function, we get :
 $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \sin 0/\cos0 $ =$\lim_{x\to 0^+} 1/0 = \infty$ which is not correct

So, How to figure out that the limit goes to $-\infty$ as x approaches zero from right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \tan{\left( 2x + \tfrac\pi 2 \right)} = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\sin{\left( 2x + \tfrac\pi 2 \right)}}{\cos{\left( 2x + \tfrac\pi 2 \right)}} = \frac{1}{0^-} = -\infty$$
because we approach $\cos \frac \pi 2$ from angles greater than $\frac \pi 2$ where $\cos$ is negative.